# Add an outgoing interceptor on JMS messages

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I'm working on some project where I'm building some JMS messages that I want to send using `JmsTemplate`, which is initialized in a Spring Boot app, via JNDI naming.

As my Broker is `IBM MQ Series`, I need to change the encoding value in the outgoing XML message, so I'm sure the broker will understand the message.

I haven't seen anywhere on the `JmsTemplate`settings, or the `ConnectionFactory` JmsTemplate need to be initialized, where to put some outgoing interceptors.

If anyone got some ideas, or any workaround or some framework/library that could help, feel free to give me some hint.

Thanks

Comment: What value do you need to change,  why not set it to the correct value before sending?

Comment: I need to change the `encoding` value in the XML tag at the beginning of the document. And I can't access it before the message is built

Comment: Add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the `convertAndSend` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using JAXB to create the XML message.

Configure your `JmsTemplate` with a [MarshallingMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MarshallingMessageConverter.html) that uses a [Jaxb2Marshaller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html) where you can set the marshaller property [JAXB_ENCODING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html?is-external=true#JAXB_ENCODING):

```
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller(); 
Map properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "YOUR-ENCODING");
jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(properties);
jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("your.package");

JmsTemplate jms = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
jms.setMessageConverter(new MarshallingMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller));
...
jms.convertAndSend(yourObject);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer at it fits my need. Yet, I didn't want to use JAXB to convert my message as JMS Template can do it by itself.

Comment: As far as I know the `JmsTemplate` uses as default the [SimpleMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/SimpleMessageConverter.html). How did you create your XML without configuring the `MarshallingMessageConverter`?